# Can I use different set of kafka brokers for storing the state of Kafka streams application?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I just want to know if its possible to use a different set of brokers for storing the kafka streams state topics.
And also, is it possible to use another storage system, like amazon s3 as kafka streams sink with exactly once semantics? I don't want to first use an output topic, then consume from it and store in s3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Streams can only use one cluster for its data

You'd need to use Kafka Connect to write to S3 prior to KIP-405

Comment: Can I implement my own sink in kafka streams?

Comment: Kafka Streams doesn't use a term "sink", and it can only write `to()` or `through()` a topic in the same cluster. You can write a SinkTask in the Connect API, sure

Comment: Is there a plan in kafka streams to support more than one kafka clusters in future?

Comment: I don't see anything related to this in docs.

Comment: There's nothing in the docs because it's not possible, and there are alternative solutions to this problem like using MirrorMaker2